# how to do CRUD operations on codeflower graph in SVG d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I newbie in d3.js. I have developed network topology graph using d3.js (codeflower graph).
I want to do CRUD operation on node of topology.

Can anybody suggest me. what should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Use the update/enter/exit pattern. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html).

Comment: Thanks lars, I want the popup when i mouse over on node where i can delete the node edit the details of node. is it possible by above tutorial you referred?

Comment: The tutorial won't tell you how to do exactly that, no.

Comment: I know that but i wanna ask Is it possible or not using this tutorial? Anyway i will try first then i come to you. Thanks